# Multiple properties in a NativeScript binding expression

Tags: javascript, data-binding, nativescript

How can I use multiple nested properties of an observable in a binding expression?

`map` is an observable with two properties, `isEnabled` and `isPaused`, that is nested within an observable, that is itself bound to page.bindingContext. If either properties are `true` I wish to do something. In this case, change the label's text.

```
<Label text="{{ map.isEnabled, map.isEnabled || map.isPaused, map.isPaused  }}" />
```

^ Text output changes from `true` to `false` correctly as the properties change.

```
<Label text="{{ map.isEnabled, map.isEnabled || map.isPaused, map.isPaused ? 'Text one' : 'Text two' }}" />
```

^ Text output is still `true` or `false`. The ternary is completely ignored.

What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: See docs: http://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/data-binding#binding-to-an-event-in-xml   `ternary operator var1 ? var2 : var3 Evaluating the value of var1 and if true, returns var2, else returns var3.`

Comment: Sorry, did you find the solution?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with the comma expression you're using. Can you please explain that to me? How is it different from this I wonder:

```
<Label text="{{ map.isEnabled || map.isPaused ? 'Text one' : 'Text two' }}" />
```

Comment: Have a read of the "Using expressions for binding" section of the docs. The comma syntax is explained there. http://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/data-binding#using-expressions-for-bindings

Comment: Thanks, interesting concept.